# Validating/Trusting Sharepoint Online STS token

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint, saml-2.0, sharepoint-online

I may have the wrong idea of how I should go about these things, but this is currently the case:
I have a WebApi service that accepts requests from Sharepoint Online (SPO), which have SAML2 token passed within. The SAML2 token is issued by SPO STS, and I will need to validate the token, and extract claims out of it.
My question is **how do I validate the token?** Is there a way to **trust** the STS somehow, so I can just verify the signature (possibly will have to decrypt the token as well) all in-place? If not, and I have to make another call to STS, what should be the endpoint to validate the token? I couldn't find much documentation on this.

Comment: this might help https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110870/how-to-use-saml-token-to-authenticate-sharepont-2013-online

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure it's exactly what I need. I need the other way, meaning a token that arrives at my service and was issued by O365's STS, needs to be validated/trusted by my service. My question is how do I validate the token from O365 STS, meaning trusting the STS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using O365 as STS or IdP and that provides the SAML2.0 Assertion to your service, then you have to get its X509Certificate (to verify the signature of received SAML2.0 Assertion) from metadata link: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantDomainName>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`.

Make sure you retrieve X509Certificate from EntityDescriptor-> IDPSSODescriptor-> KeyDescriptor use="signing" -> KeyInfo-> X509Data-> X509Certificate.